# How can we delete space with a shell script?

Tags: bash, shell

I did a script in order to display different things, in different case.
The script is :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# declare an array, to store stuff in
declare -a myArray
shopt -s nocasematch

# read the full file into the array
# This while loop terminates when pressing CTRL-D
i=1
while read -r line; do
   myArray[i]="${line}"
   ((i++))   
done < /dev/stdin

# Process the array
for ((j=1;j<i;++j)); do
   # perform your actions here on myArray[j]

    case "${myArray[j]}" in
    bob)
        echo  "boy"
        ;;
    alicia)
        echo "girl" 
        ;;
    cookie)
        echo "dog" 
        ;;
    *)
        echo "unknown" "${myArray[j]}"
        ;;

    esac

done
```

But I have a problem, when I execute the code with this command:

```
cat input.txt | ./prog.sh > file.txt
```

I have the following input:

```
bob
alicia
amhed
cookie


daniel
```

In this input I have so space, but when I run my program I don't obtain this right result.  I need my code not to take into account spaces, but if it take care about the space, is wrote "unknown" on the OUTPOUT file.txt

and I obtain the result :

```
boy
girl
unknown amhed
dog
unknown 
unknown 
unknown daniel
```

So can I eliminate/delete the space without touching the input file?

Comment: What is the expected output? Did you not want to process `daniel` in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You can read from stdin and process each line and avoid array creation.
- Use `&& [[ -n $line ]]` to make sure you process only non-empty lines.
- By default `read` command reads it from `/dev/stdin` so you can omit `< /dev/stdin` from your code.

**Code:**

```
shopt -s nocasematch

while read -r line && [[ -n $line ]]; do

    case "$line" in
    bob)
        echo  "boy"
        ;;
    alicia)
        echo "girl"
        ;;
    cookie)
        echo "dog"
        ;;
    *)
        echo "unknown $line"
        ;;
    esac

done
```

Run it as:

```
./prog.sh < input.txt
```

**Output:**

```
boy
girl
unknown amhed
dog
```

Comment: I need to keep all the code I put on my post, I just want to know what can I add to delete the space and to obtain your output, I am sorry but your answer it is not really want I want, have you got an other idea please?

Comment: In your code you can change `while read -r line; do` line to `while read -r line && [[ -n $line ]]; do` to make it work

Comment: thank you for you answer, it works and I understand now my problem

Answer (score 1):

why do this in `bash`?

with `awk`

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{n=split("bob boy alicia girl cookie dog",x);   
             for(i=1;i<n;i+=2) a[x[i]]=x[i+1]}              # build the lookup table

            {print $1 in a?a[$1]:"unknown "$1}' file

boy
girl
unknown amhed
dog
unknown 
unknown 
unknown daniel
```

you can externalize the lookup map to another file as well, so that the code doesn't need to be modified if either values change.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do nothing when the input line is empty, you can add that to your `case`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# declare an array, to store stuff in
declare -a myArray
shopt -s nocasematch

# read the full file into the array
# This while loop terminates when pressing CTRL-D
i=1
while read -r line; do
   myArray[i]="${line}"
   ((i++))
done < /dev/stdin

# Process the array
for ((j=1;j<i;++j)); do
   # perform your actions here on myArray[j]

    case "${myArray[j]}" in
    "") # This is an empty line, skip it
        ;;
    bob)
        echo  "boy"
        ;;
    alicia)
        echo "girl"
        ;;
    cookie)
        echo "dog"
        ;;
    *)
        echo "unknown" "${myArray[j]}"
        ;;

    esac

done
```

Alternatively, check whether the line you read was empty before adding it to the array.